# Prove that the number of ways of arranging $p$ $1's$ and $q$ $0's$ in a line such that no two $1's$ are adjacent is ${q+1 \choose p}.$

Tags: combinatorics

If we can prove that the total number of ways will be ${q \choose p} + {q \choose p-1}$. It will suffice. Again, I don't know if $p > q$ or the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line up the $q$ zeros in a row.  This creates $q + 1$ spaces, $q - 1$ between successive zeros and two at the ends of the row.  For instance, if there are ten zeros, we have eleven spaces.
$$\square 0 \square 0 \square 0 \square 0 \square 0 \square 0 \square 0 \square 0 \square 0 \square 0 \square$$ 
To separate the $p$ ones, we must choose $p$ of these $q + 1$ spaces in which to place a $1$.

Note that if $p > q + 1$, the task is impossible since at least two ones must be adjacent.  However, the result still holds since $\binom{q + 1}{p} = 0$ if $p > q + 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: each $1$ is either in the last position or is followed by a $0$.

Comment: Then the form ${q \choose p} + {q \choose p-1}$ is coming . If the $1$ is in the first position, then the no of ways ${q \choose p-1}$. And if it is not in the 1st position, then the number of ways ${q \choose p}$. Then adding those two, we get ${q+1 \choose p}$.